# Why no CPU consumption during class instantiation?

Tags: c++

I created a loop that instantiates a class 1 billion times and was very surprised to see that it ran in 0ms and consumed no CPU time according to Windows task manager.

As you can see from the code below, I am obviously not doing anything with the default constructor but I had assumed that there would be a significant CPU hit creating then destroying the class over and over again.  Can someone explain why there is no noticeable CPU hit?

```
class Cmytest {
public:
  int  lookup();
  bool create_rec();
  bool delete_rec();
};

void test() {
  for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
    Cmytest mytest;
  }
}

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

After running the test above, I wanted to see what would happen if I ran test() in two different threads (2 billion iterations but code not included to keep post concise) and there was no noticeable difference.

Please advise, thank you!

UPDATE:

The reason for asking this is because I use composition quite often and I have a class with a member to Cmytest.  Depending on certain data conditions, Cmytest's members will be executed and in other cases, it does nothing.  It is a long running web application and I am always concerned about efficiency.

FINAL UPDATE:

I decided to have the instance do something (to insure that it's not just optimizing to ignore the loop that does nothing). I added the following member as seen here:

```
Cmytest::void count(int& i) {
  i++;
}
```

Then I called it within the loop:

```
int iter=0;
void test() {
  for (int i=0; i<1000000000; i++) {
    Cmytest mytest;
    mytest.count(iter);
  }
}
```

The results were 1 billion and if run in two threads, 2 billion which is correct. By this, I can only infer that work is being done and the object is being reused, which explains the efficiency that I observe.

Comment: The compiler can optimize the loop out if it has no observable effects.

Comment: Compiler said: "nothing's going on here, let's throw this loop away".

Comment: `Cmytest mytest;` Any decent compiler could optimize this out as long there aren't any side effects.

Comment: If you are compiling in release, most probably it's optimized away, the compiler understand that you are no using `mytest` variable anywhere and by this is not necessary

Comment: Add a printf or something not compiler-optimizable-away to it and you'll see the slowdown you were expecting.

Comment: Did anyone mention it is optimized away?

Comment: Did you print the assembly code?  The truth is in the assembly code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, about printing the assembly, sadly I am not that advanced.

Comment: @juanchopanza and jrok, in the simplistic example above, it can be assumed that a smart compiler can throw the loop away, but what if there are some conditions causing Cmytest members to be executed?

Comment: It depends. But you are asking about the code you have shown. It sounds like you need to ask a different question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under the "as-if rule", the compiler is allowed to transform your program in any way it pleases such that the observable side effects remain the same †. Your program has no observable side effects other than returning `0`, so almost the entirety of the program can be resolved to nothing.

Even if we ignore this, when an object is declared in a loop, compilers typically reuse the same object over and over without having to reallocate memory (but would need to reinitialise the object). In this example, the compiler can probably even see that the object remains untouched and can be reused without having to reinitialise it. Regardless, your class has no state to initialise anyway.

To demonstrate, if I compile your code with maximum optimisations in Clang, the resulting assembly for the `test` function is as follows:

```
_Z4testv:
    .cfi_startproc
    ret
```

It just returns immediately.

<sub>† And copy elision is an optimisation that is explicitly allowed even if it does modify the observable side effects of the program.</sub>

Comment: Not sure about the last edit. It's on the stack which is easy to allocate anyway. If it's a `std::string` for example, it will reallocate dynamic memory each iteration.

Comment: @NeilKirk I was just trying to avoid stack/heap terminology, but yeah, destruction and initialisation still needs to occur in the general case.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, before running the test above, I was going to make Cmytest dynamic and instantiate it only after program logic proved that the class would be needed. That I why I was so surprised by the results. I figured that I'd be wasting both ram and cpu by not doing it dynamically but I think that I was wrong. It really does look like creating the class on the stack is fine.  Would you agree?  Thanks again.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran If anything, allocating dynamically will be slower (requesting memory from the OS and indirection).

Comment: Regarding ellision of ctor+dtor for each loop iteration: That only works if the compiler knows they don't have observable side-effects, like here.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, I think that what you mentioned about the compiler uses the same object over and over without having to reallocate memory is the reason for the efficiency.  My application is multi-threaded and I have noticed in the past that objects allocated on the stack will retain data which causes me to 'clean up' each object (in its constructor) prior to using it even though I create the instance in the stack. I used to wonder why but never gave it too much thought since I'd just clean up the objects members in the constructor.

Comment: @CarolineBeltran You should always ensure your class members are initialised properly in the constructor. It is true that if you don't you may very well get the previous instance's data, but this is undefined behaviour. But yes, good observation.

Comment: @JosephMansfield, I updated my original post the best way I could to put to a test the second paragraph from your accepted answer. I don't see it any other way, your second paragraph has to be the answer. I'm fully satisfied now.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the compiler and the flags you pass to it, it may decide to optimize out code that has no effect. In this case you declare a variable that is never used and thus compiler decides it is safe to optimize this code out thus it never gets executed.